# How come I can't see rows in sysobjects for objects that I know exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am a member only of the `db_datareader` role on a database, and I cannot see rows in `sysobjects` for stored procedures that I know exist.

Additionally, in SQL Server Managedemnt Studio, expanding the `Programmability -> Stored Procedures` node in Object Explorer does not show any stored procedures.

Is this due to insufficient permissions? If so, what permissions do I need in order to be able to see all rows in `sysobjects`, and also to see what permissions have been granted on each object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably lacking [VIEW DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808.aspx) permission. To get permission on an entire schema, use:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [UserName]
```

For an individual procedure:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON YourStoredProcedureName TO [UserName]
```

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, it did indeed. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is related to a permissions issue.  Try adding yourself to this role db_ddladmin for that database.

Info on db_ddladmin: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190667(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I think Joe Stefanelli has a better answer

Answer (score 0):

are you using the database? the correct one?

```
use [db_x]
go
select * from sysobjects
where type = 'P'
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct database. Additionally, in SQL Server Managedemnt Studio, expanding the `Programmability -> Stored Procedures` node in Object Explorer does not show any stored procedures.